# Изменение длины геометрического вектора

Tags: c++, sfml

Есть функция setLength для изменения длины вектора (геометрического) на указанный параметром **без изменения его направления**.

Вот функция

```
Vector2f setLength(Vector2f startPos, Vector2f currentPos, double neededLength)
{
    double currentLength = getLength(startPos, currentPos); 
    //getLength - отдельная написанная мною функция, возвращает длину вектора

    double factorLength = neededLength / currentLength; 
    //factorLength - коэффициент разности нужной длины и текущей

    return Vector2f(currentPos.x * factorLength, currentPos.y * factorLength);
}
```

сама функция должна возвращать координаты конца вектора при заданной длине и с тем же направлением

но почему то итоговая длина вектора не соответствует нужной (то больше, то меньше). Кроме этого само направление вектора изменяется. Это точно не ошибка в getLength, там все максимально просто (длина вектора по теореме Пифагора), но все же ее я тоже укажу

```
double getLength(Vector2f firstdot, Vector2f seconddot)
{
    return sqrt(pow(firstdot.x - seconddot.y, 2) + pow(firstdot.y - seconddot.y, 2));
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Умножение на factorLength работает, когда вектор выходит из начала координат, а не когда это отрезок из двух точек.

Comment: `pow(firstdot.x - seconddot.y, 2)` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что Вы не знаете, что такое "вектор".

```
return Vector2f(
  (currentPos.x - startPos.x) * factorLength + startPos.x, 
  (currentPos.y - startPos.y) * factorLength + startPos.y
);
```

Comment: Благодарю за наводку на правильный ответ, однако ваш код  не решает проблему

Comment: @Distraw Мой код *решает* проблему. Вы неправильно вызываете Вашу функцию `setLength`. Не говоря уже о том, что Вы держите в секрете входные, ожидаемые выходные и получаемые выходные данные.

Comment: Вы правы, так как я только сейчас заметил, что я не указал то, что функция должна возвращать. По задумке, она должна возвращать координаты второй точки (конца вектора), при которой длина изменяется на указанную и сохраняется направление. Если не сложно, можете помочь с такими условиями?

Например при входных данных setLength(Vector2f(0, 0), Vector2f(1, 1), 5) ожидается, что функция вернет Vector2f(3.5355, 3.5355), поскольку вектор с началом в точке {0, 0} и концом в точке {3.5355, 3.5355} приблизительно имеет длину 5 (4,999952 - более точное значение, не столь важно)

Comment: @Distraw Изменил.